# same number is giving output for mobile_number string

Tags: android, string

Hi in the below code below mobile is
mobile:`["9841910799","04651226127","9639355527","04428213134","8939597777","04428223060","04428311001","9822363585","8318043412","9919588852","9919588852","9919588852","9828722750","8875518030","9862145100","9414135437","9414135437"]`

```
 String mobile=sharedPreferences.getString("mobile",null);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
     try {
                                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(mobile);
                                    String[] strArr = new String[jsonArray.length()];

                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                        strArr[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
                                        mobile_number1= String.valueOf(strArr[i]);

                                        for(int j=0;j<mobile_number1.length();j++){
                                            mobile_number= String.valueOf(mobile_number1.toCharArray());
                                        }
                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

For every time I am getting the single number

expected output

```
mobile_number=9841910799
9841910797
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow updated code

```
 String mobile=sharedPreferences.getString("mobile",null);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
     try {
                                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(mobile);
                                    String[] strArr = new String[jsonArray.length()];

                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                        strArr[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
                                        mobile_number1= String.valueOf(strArr[i]);

                                        for(int j=0;j<mobile_number1.length();j++){
                                            mobile_number=mobile_number+ String.valueOf(mobile_number1.toCharArray());
                                        }
                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

As per my understanding the problem, you are assigning value every time as the new in mobile_number variable, not assigning previous plus new number.

Comment: one by one number want to display it

Comment: it is not worhing